# How to show email performance data in a dashboard in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

We have a requirement of displaying email performance data (for eg: Open rate, click rate, bounce rate, etc etc)  for all emails in a dashboard in Marketing Cloud. I am aware of generating reports but not sure about dashboard creation. Could someone help me out ?

Comment: There is no out of the box dashboards available for showing general email metrics for SFMC. My suggestion is to build a solution based on a [custom app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/create-a-mc-app.htm) where you will be able to fetch the metrics and show them using custom charts, gauges, etc. However a detailed guidance on how to achieve this is outside of this site's scope.

Comment: If you have the Marketing Cloud Connector, you can leverage reports on Sales/Service Cloud. You'll be limited to data synchronized back to Sales/Service, but you'll get much more choices in term of report types/objects ..

Comment: Hi Lukas. Thanks for your response and I am wondering how we could connect in order to seek your assistance regarding the detailed guidance.

Comment: Hi @SourabMund . If you require help from Salesforce, which goes beyond what support provides, my advice will be to involve their professional services. This is however a billable engagement.